Creating C# class from database rows
I have C# classes whose members I need to store as individual rows in the database. Following is a sample class structure:
public class Root
{
    public Prius Prius { get; set; }
}

public class Prius
{
    public int SteeringWheel { get; set; }
    public Wheels Wheels { get; set; }
    public Power Power { get; set; }
}

public class Wheels
{
    public int Front { get; set; }
    public int Rear { get; set; }
}

public class Power
{
    public Gasoline Gasoline { get; set; }
    public Battery Battery { get; set; }
}

public class Gasoline
{
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
}

public class Battery
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
}

Hard Requirements:

The individual values need to be stored in database, with additional columns.
Keys will have multiple versions. So when the application will query the table, it will get only one entry (latest version) for each key.
This will only be a read operation. The application does not write back to the DB.

So, I'm thinking of storing the values in a table as:



Key
Value
Version
Metadata col 1
More columns...




Prius:SteeringWheel
0
1
test
....


Prius:SteeringWheel
1
2
test
....


Prius:Wheels:Front
2
1
test
....


Prius:Wheels:Rear
2
1
test
....


...remaining rows
...
...
...
....



Here's my approach to create C# object(s) from these values:

Read all values at once (I'm using EF Core)
Create C# object(s)

These objects will then be passed to other classes in my application via constructor parameters.
I have a few questions:

Going with this approach, what is the easiest way to accomplish this? By this, I mean that I wish to leverage existing C#/.Net Framework features to do this using minimal code versus writing my own code.
Is this the best approach to accomplish what I need? If not, please suggest alternative ideas.

Edit 1:

Updated json, removed duplicate 'wheels' property.
I want to avoid creating EF entities as if a property gets added/removed in the future, I just want to update the code and not update DB schema. Additionally, keys will have multiple versions and only the latest will be read.

Edit 2:

Added all requirements
Replaced json example with C#

Thanks,

1. Read all values at once (I'm using EF Core) - The job is done!

If you're going to put this in a database, you might want to consider normalization. The Wheels and Power probably belong in separate tables with a foreign key relationship. Also, you have two properties called "Wheels" which cannot be represented in a single class and may not serialize well to JSON. Also, why on Earth would you serialize to JSON just to convert back to a class? Just map the properties.

Why not use actual EF Entities, with properties that refer to other Entities? Why the need or wish for a JSON detour on both write and read? This kind of mapping and storing is what EF was built to do and it does a great job at it.

@PeterB: I want to avoid creating EF entities as if a property gets added/removed in the future, I just want to update the code and not update DB schema. Also, I'm not saying I wish to have the Json detour, just thought of it as an option.

@JohnWu: I've removed duplicate entry for the 'Wheels' property, sorry that was an error.

Don't build a database framework within a database framework. Otherwise known as an inner platform. I know it's tempting, in an attempt to reduce future maintenance. But it's not worth it. The future maintenance of your weird database system will end up being more work than just using the features of a database engine. Trust me on this one.

Note that most database engines do have some support for saving json into column values, and you can use those features. But just keep it to one type per column. Don't implement something that stores different json in different rows.
